When to add signals coherently and incoherently?
I just learned in transmission electron microscopy about coherent and incoherent summation. I can't seem to wrap my head around the fact that intensities can be added incoherently. Why can you do that? And more importantly, when can you do that? Like, shouldn't the intensity be always be added coherently because either the waves are in phase or they are not, don't they?


Like, shouldn't the intensity be always be added coherently because either the waves are in phase or they are not, don't they?

If you have two sources that aren't coherent, then they won't be at exactly the same frequency. This means that the points where they are in phase and out of phase will not stay the same for any appreciable amount of time. In the case of optical sources, they can easily change much faster than our detector can follow.
Mathematically, the intensity is proportional to the time average of the field strength squared, so for a point of interference between two beams we have
$$I\propto \left<(E_1+E_2)^2\right>.$$
This can be expanded as
$$I\propto \left<E_1^2 + E_1E_2 +E_2^2\right>.$$
In the coherent case, the $\left<E_1E_2\right>$ term may be non-zero and contributes to the intensity. In the incoherent case, the phase relationship between $E_1$ and $E_2$ changes rapidly and therefore the time average goes to 0, leaving
$$I\propto \left<E_1^2 + E_2^2\right>$$, and since the two fields are not correlated in time, the two terms can be averaged seperately,
$$I\propto \left<E_1^2\right>+\left<E_2^2\right>$$
or
$$I = I_1 + I_2$$

Okay got it! Now to my next question: When can you do that? I heard for example that the energy has to be similar to add them coherently. But why?

@DatHo Coherency and degree of coherency is a whole topic of its own, but in optics it will mainly only happen when either the two sources are actually made by splitting a single original source beam, or when one source is phase-locked to the other (and phase-locking an optical source is not a trivial thing to do). Even two HeNe lasers emitting at 632.8 nm will not be coherent.

Simply not all sources and waves are coherent to each other, and thus they can not experience coherent interference. Two speakers, placed apart and playing different songs are not coherent to each other, and thus that music will not destructively or constructively interfere.
